# A number to LCD display in assembly in PIC16Fxx

Tags: assembly, pic

I am using PIC16.

I am stuck on how to convert a number(binary/hex/decimal) in assembly to ASCII to be displayed in an LCD display for example:

I have a number here stored in a register

number = 0x04d2 (1234 in decimal)

```
 0x30 = 0x04
 0x31 = 0xd2
```

How would i go about to convert it to ASCII so that the LCD would display the 1234 in the display?

without using division.

Comment: What LCD did you have connected?

Comment: the specific model is LM016L. I already know how to display to the lcd, i am just having trouble spliting the number to its ascii counterpart

Comment: if you know of an lcd that takes in straight binary, that would also help, since i am only making a very basic calculator i do not need letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it work here is how i did it.

B_HIGH_BYTE and B_LOW_BYTE are the number you want to be converted to ASCII , everything else here is just a temporary variables

I manually divided the number by d'10000' , d'1000', d'100' , d'10' and the last one is whatever is left :)

might not be the fastest way buy made it to work for my needs. Thank you for all you suggestions.

```html
;====================================SPECIAL DIVISION========================   
SPECIAL_DIVISION
    
    clrf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER 
    clrf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE 
    clrf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE 

    clrf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_HIGH_BYTE 
    clrf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_LOW_BYTE 
    
    movf B_HIGH_BYTE, 0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE
    
    movf B_LOW_BYTE, 0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE
    
    
    loop_SD         ;getting 5th digit
 movf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,0
 movwf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_HIGH_BYTE 
 
 movf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE,0
 movwf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_LOW_BYTE 
    
 movlw 0x10
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE,1
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+2
 goto $+3
 movlw 0x01
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,1
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+7
 
 movlw 0x27
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,1
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+3
 incf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER
    goto loop_SD
    
    movf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER,0
    addlw 0x30
    call display_digit

    clrf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER

    movf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_HIGH_BYTE,0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE

    movf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_LOW_BYTE,0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE

    loop_SD2      ;getting 4th digit
 movf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,0
 movwf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_HIGH_BYTE 
 
 movf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE,0
 movwf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_LOW_BYTE 
    
 movlw 0xe8
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE,1
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+2
 goto $+3
 movlw 0x01
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,1
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+7
 
 movlw 0x03
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,1
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+3
 incf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER
    goto loop_SD2
    
    movf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER,0
    addlw 0x30
    call display_digit

    clrf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER

    movf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_HIGH_BYTE,0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE

    movf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_LOW_BYTE,0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE
    
    loop_SD3      ;getting 3rd digit
 movf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,0
 movwf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_HIGH_BYTE 
 
 movf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE,0
 movwf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_LOW_BYTE 
    
 movlw 0x64
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE,1
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+2
 goto $+3
 movlw 0x01
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,1
 
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+3
 incf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER
    goto loop_SD3
    
    movf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER,0
    addlw 0x30
    call display_digit

    clrf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER

    movf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_HIGH_BYTE,0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE

    movf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_LOW_BYTE,0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE
    
    loop_SD4      ;getting 2nd digit
 movf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,0
 movwf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_HIGH_BYTE 
 
 movf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE,0
 movwf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_LOW_BYTE 
    
 movlw 0x0a
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE,1
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+2
 goto $+3
 movlw 0x01
 subwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE,1
 
 btfss STATUS,0
 goto $+3
 
 incf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER
    goto loop_SD4
    
    movf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER,0
    addlw 0x30
    call display_digit

    clrf SPECIAL_DIV_COUNTER

    movf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_HIGH_BYTE,0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_HIGH_BYTE

    movf SPECIAL_DIV_PREV_ANS_LOW_BYTE,0
    movwf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE
    
    
    movf SPECIAL_DIV_LOW_BYTE,0     ;getting 1st digit
    addlw 0x30
    call display_digit
    
  
    
    
    
    
return
```

Answer (score 2):

In PIC16 assembler looks 16 bit division by 10 like...

```
;Input RegA2 as low byte RegA1 as High byte
;Result of division by 10 is stored back to RegA2 and RegA1
;Remainder of division is stored in RegA0
;RegAE is temporary storage
        clrf    RegA0       
        movlw   16
        movwf   RegAE
        lslf    RegA2, f
divI16by_c10_        
        rlf     RegA1, f
        rlf     RegA0, f       
        movlw   10
        subwf   RegA0, f
        btfsc   Carry
        bra     divI16by_c10_OK
        addwfc  RegA0, f
        bcf     Carry
divI16by_c10_OK        
        rlf     RegA2, f
        decfsz  RegAE, f
        bra     divI16by_c10_
        return
```

Just copy to C language...

Comment: Thank you i am trying to make a calculator , this will be helpfull for my division function

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in C, but the same can be done in assembly with few changes.

```
static void Console_printNum(
    uint32_t num,
    uint8_t base,
    uint8_t point)
{
    #define CHAR_BUFSIZE 33
    const char* const numchars[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
        "A","B","C","D","E","F"};
    const char* buf[CHAR_BUFSIZE];
    const char** pStr = &(buf[CHAR_BUFSIZE-1]);

    do {
        *(--pStr) = numchars[num % base];
        num /= base;
        } while( num != 0 );

    while( pStr < &buf[CHAR_BUFSIZE-1] ) {    //copy the buffer into the queue
        if((&buf[CHAR_BUFSIZE-1] - pStr) == point) {
            Console_printStr(".");                       //print decimal point
        }
        Console_printStr(*pStr++);
    }
}
```

Comment: due to limitations, i cannot use division

Answer (score 0):

To convert a number into ASCII you just had to add `0x30`.

0 dezimal    0x30 ASCII
1 dezimal    0x30 ASCII
2 dezimal    0x32 ASCII
...

But of course you had to split your number into single digits.

Comment: thats where i am stuck, spliting them into single digits.

Comment: @Jack I guess you need division by 10, 100 and 1000. But of course you could do that with a PIC16.

Answer (score 0):

> How would i go about to convert it to ASCII so that the LCD would
>   display the 1234 in the display?
>
> without using division.

The "without using division" is the tricky part. The first step is to convert a 16-bit binary number to a BCD representation. The best available method is know by several names, the most common is the "double dabble" algorithm. This is an example for the PIC16F:

```
;
; See:
;   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble
;
BIN2BCD_VAR     UDATA
A_reg:      res     2
D_reg:      res     3
mBits:      res     1

BIN2BCD_CODE    CODE
;
; Function: Bin2BCD
; Input:    A_reg, 16-bit binary
;
; Output:   D_reg, 3 bytes of packed BCD digits
;
Bin2BCD:
    banksel D_reg
    clrf    D_reg+0         ; Clear result
    clrf    D_reg+1
    clrf    D_reg+2
    movlw   D'16'           ; Set bit counter
    movwf   mBits

ConvertBit:
    movlw   H'33'           ; Correct BCD value so that
    addwf   D_reg+0,F       ; subsequent shift yields
    btfsc   D_reg+0,.3      ; correct value.
    andlw   H'F0'
    btfsc   D_reg+0,.7
    andlw   H'0F'
    subwf   D_reg+0,F

    movlw   H'33'
    addwf   D_reg+1,F
    btfsc   D_reg+1,.3
    andlw   H'F0'
    btfsc   D_reg+1,.7
    andlw   H'0F'
    subwf   D_reg+1,F

    rlf     A_reg+0,F       ; Shift out a binary bit ...
    rlf     A_reg+1,F

    rlf     D_reg+0,F       ; ... and into BCD value.
    rlf     D_reg+1,F
    rlf     D_reg+2,F

    decfsz  mBits,F         ; Repeat for all bits
    goto    ConvertBit
    return
```

The next part is to convert the BCD representation to ASCII characters 4-bits at a time.

I will leave this job to the Original Poster. Good luck.